# STS Build All button greyed out

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-data

I installed STS  After I opened STS, Project -> build all button is greyed out for any Spring Data project.
So I can't do any build.

I have JDK 1.7 and maven 3.05 installed.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse normally has "Build Automatically" enabled by default. That one is probably not greyed out, right (so you can switch it off, but not sure why you'd want to)?